# OpenJDK builds and javaws bin file

Tags: java, java-web-start, redhat-openjdk

I understand that Java Web Start is deprecated and not present in Java SE 11 and later.

I bumped into the Red Hat distribution of OpenJDK which says "OpenJDK 11 Windows installer includes an additional component - Web Start deployment protocol implementation based on IcedTea-Web open-source project." [Red Hat's OpenJDK Overview](https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/overview/). I thought "well they added it".

I downloaded it but in /bin there isn't any trace of javaws.

I also downloaded the OpenJDK 8 from Red Hat, and again, no trace of javaws in /bin. I downloaded the Reference Implementation builds of Java SE 8 from Oracle from https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8 and again, no trace of javaws.

What am I missing?

P.S. despite a programmer, I know nothing of Java

Comment: Is there `$JAVA_HOME/javaws` directory after the installation? Perhaps the executable was moved inside this directory? Hard to tell as one needs RedHat account to download this distribution.

Comment: I looked for javaws in the entire installation directory, nothing found. Btw, anyone can make a RedHat account ;)

Comment: @kai thanks. I'm working on a Windows machine and from Red Hat I downloaded the Windows installer. It's specified that the Windows installer should include WS. Anyone knows if there is an Icedtea version available for Windows?

Comment: So I may find javaws only on 32bit builds of jdk... I'm on mobile now and I cannot check. If so, is the 32bit build of jdk going to work on a Windows 10 64bit?

Comment: sorry, I missed the windows part;)

Comment: Downloaded the x86 versions of OpenJDK 8 from Red Hat and [ojdk](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/releases) and no trace of javaws. For now, its only present in the builds of the Oracle's JDK 8 (commercial).

Comment: Also the Red Hat msi installer of version 11 (up to now I used tar.gz archives) does not provide javaws. This is a mistery to me since it's so clearly stated that it should be there.

Answer (score 3):

Please turn to icedtea-web project. It is independent project, and in one way or another, it is what all distros are packing as javaws - http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/IcedTea-Web

Comment: What am I supposed to do in Windows? Just install the binaries from http://icedtea.wildebeest.org/download/icedtea-web-binaries/1.8/windows/ and it will magically work with Red Hat's OpenJDK 11?

Comment: Yes. that  is exactly what you should do. Please note, icedtea-webmoved to githb, and is now cooperating with adoptpenjdk and karakun, to provide more friendly user expereince: https://github.com/adoptopenjdk/icedtea-web

Comment: Just FYI if anyone is looking at IcedTea-Web; it only supports 64bit.  If you have to deal with legacy 32bit Java files (such as the remote console for a Lenovo TS200) , it will not work for you.  I thought that should be here in case they thought it might fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Red Hat Java 8 there are TWO downloads available for WINDOWS:

- zip
- msi

The MSI version does NOT contain the \webstart folder.

The zip version DOES contain the \webatart folder.

\redhat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232-3.b09.redhat.windows.x86_64\webstart\javaws.exe

Separately, unlike Oracle Java, openJDK does NOT have a Java console that shows output from the app when running.

But that output is written to a txt file. FOUND IT here:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openjdk/8/pdf/troubleshooting_openjdk_8_for_windows/OpenJDK-8-Troubleshooting_OpenJDK_8_for_Windows-en-US.pdf

C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232-3.b09.redhat.windows.x86_64\webstart\javaws_last_log.txt