# javaws.exe not found in jre/bin directory

Tags: java, jnlp

I want to execute a Java Network Launching Protocol (.jnlp) file on my windows 10 system. 
I am using OpenJDK 1.8. According tho the internet resources , I need javaws.exe executable to execute the .jnlp file. It is generally available in jre/bin directory. In my installation directory it is not available.

From where can i get javaws.exe file for OpenJDK

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55186796/openjdk-builds-and-javaws-bin-file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java WebStart is not included in OpenJDK.
See this: [Openjdk and Java webstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55930547/openjdk-and-java-webstart)

You can try to use other OpenJDK implementations, such as AdoptOpenJDK, which has IcedTeaWeb optionally packaged into the JDK.
https://adoptopenjdk.net/

IcedTeaWeb is an alternative to original WebStart and works almost the same from user point of view when using eg. AdoptOpenJDK.

Comment: javaws binaries - http://icedtea.wildebeest.org/download/icedtea-web-binaries/1.8/. 
For windows .msi file http://icedtea.wildebeest.org/download/icedtea-web-binaries/1.8/windows/